# Как связать таблицы в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Проектирую БД для "онлайн журнала". И запутался в связях. Как грамотно связать users и teachers, students (при условии, что студент не может быть преподавателем и наоборот). На данный момент таблицы учителя и студенты пустые, но там будут внешние ключи. [image: База данных выглядит так]

Comment: *Как связать таблицы в базе данных?* таблицы в базах данных связываются применением ограничения внешнего ключа (FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT). В большинстве СУБД для этого требуется наличие индексов по связываемым полям, в т.ч. на стороне "один" - уникального/первичного. *Как грамотно связать users и teachers, students (при условии, что студент не может быть преподавателем и наоборот).* В показанной схеме - никак. Она ошибочна. В ней присутствует ТРИ сущности, причём экземпляр одной является при этом экземпляром другой. Хотя на деле teacher/student - это атрибут сущности user.

Comment: Т.е. в users надо создать поле, где 0 - учитель, а 1 - студент, например.

Comment: Нет. Надо выполнить нормальный анализ, а не строить схему по некоему мистическому наитию. И уж тем более не надо пытаться "довести её до ума" мелкими заплатками. В общем случае в описанной предметной области возможны несколько разных (и все - формально правильные!) схем, зависящих от нюансов и тонкостей конкретной реализации моделируемого процесса, и только одна в Вашем конкретном случае будет полностью соответствовать. Вернитесь в начало и тщательно выполните полный анализ.

Comment: @TimaKha Изначально у вас есть пользователи, эта таблица `users` предположим где есть некие данные о нем и не важно кто это учитель или ученик или еще кто-то, это всё 1 таблица с полем `role` к примеру в которой и объявляется роль и устанавливается ссылка на права. Если права разнятся создается еще таблица с описание действий данной группы что-то типа, 1 это учитель и имеет право на то-то, се-то. Также в таблице `users` я так понял вам нужно указать привязку к группе/курсу.

Comment: @RifmaMan Как-то немного не уловил суть, как это реализовать. Можно поподробнее. Сами таблицы teachers и students разрастутся и будет там больше полей.

Comment: @TimaKha таблица учителя и студенты не нужны, это всё пользователи `users` у которых есть поле где и указан тип пользователя, все в 1 таблице, или у вас четко в условии задачи это указанно?

Comment: @RifmaMan нет не указано, просто у меня нет понимаю, куда я буду прописывать внешние ключ, например для ученика - fk_рейтинг, который будет относится только к ученику.

Comment: @TimaKha вы должны использовать `id` пользователя т.к. он уникален а привязка естественно будет лишь к тем `id`.`users`, которые являются учениками )

Comment: @RifmaMan А как понять кто из них ученик? В `Role` выставляются роли для пользователей после авторизации в самой системе. Или к `Role` сделать дополнительную таблицу, где будет привязку типа Администратор - учитель?

Comment: @TimaKha, да всё верно, отдельная таблица с правами где тип это `id`, описание Учитель, Студент и некие правила для них

Comment: @TimaKha т.е. я предлагаю рассматривать таблицу `users` как основную от которой уже будут идти связи по столбцам что это учитель или студент, что состоит в такой-то группе или/и на таком-то курсе, у учителей эти поля пустые будут, а у студентов NOT NULL, не знаю понятно ли описал, но рисовать нет возможности )

Comment: @RifmaMan т.е. сейчас вижу так. Users (id_users, fk_role) связывается с Role (id_role, fk_StudTeach), а уже Role будет связана с StudTeach (id_StudTeach, Type), которая хранит в себе студент не студент в Type, но на словах немного да не понял из чего она состоит, поэтому представил это себе так. Почему нельзя использовать 1 и 0 просто?

Comment: @TimaKha можно и некоторые так и делают если не нужно дополнительной информации кроме 1 и 0, просто в комментарии к базе заносят что значение 1 это одно, а 0 это другое.